# typescript get type of array value like in case of keys?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I can do this

```
const keys = {
    "hi": {name: "ho"}
}
type U = [keyof typeof keys][0]; // "hi"
```

Can I do it also with array values?

```
const data = [
    { name: "hi" }
];
type T = typeof data[0]["name"]; // string not "hi"
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeMYCAtgKYBcMARABYCW1MAvlgLoDcWWoksA1mQCeENARx46jKvmLkqdENVassUIQAcyMACpj1WkADN4SBBgAMbDNTllqnNZu0BVMRkFDjMA2W+eIaysOIA

Answer (score 1):

Just add `as const` to your data:

```js
const data = [
    { name: "hi" }
] as const;
```

Without `as const`, data is inferred as `Array<{name: string}>`. You do not need `as const` for `keys` as it is inferred `{hi: {name: string}}`

Answer (score 0):

Because the elements of an array can change at runtime, TS will just infer the type for data as `Array<{ name: string }>`. You have to explicitly set the type of the `data` array as `readonly`, so TS can infer the type for the first element inside the data array as `{name: "hi"}`.

The solution is to just add `as const` to the data array.

```js
const data = [
   {name: "hi"}
] as const;
// this will make TS infer the type for data as readonly[{ readonly name: "hi";}]
```

See the demo in [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeMYCAtgKYBcMARABYCW1MAvlgLowIQyiRQDcWLL2gwA1mQCe3dPhx46jKvmLkqdENVassUSQAcyMACpoYewyABm8JAgwAGNhmqqy1NoItGAqmYwSktbmBmTBgRDOTvxAA)